# Keycloack: User is able to access a realm by logging to another

Tags: keycloak, openresty

I have an nginx/openresty client to a keycloack server for authorization using openid.
I am using [lua-resty-openidc](https://github.com/zmartzone/lua-resty-openidc) to allow access to services behind the proxy.

I have created two clients at two different realms for different services.

The problem is that after a user gets authenticated at the first realm on e.g. `https://<my-server>/auth/realms/<realm1>/protocol/openid-connect/auth?response_type=code&client_id=openresty&state=...........`, he is able to directly access the other service at `realm2` as well.

What is going on here? How can I ensure that the user will only be able to access the client at the realm he authenticated against?

How can I ensure that after logout the user will no longer be able to get access until he logs in anew?

[Edit-details]
My nginx.conf for the two services is bellow.
The user first accesses  `https://<my-server>/service_1/`
and is redirected to keycloack to give his password for realm1. He provides it and is able to access service_1.

However, if after that he tries to access `https://<my-server>/service_2/`, he no longer has to authenticate, but can login although the service_2 is about a client on a different realm, with a different client_secret!

.....
location /service_1/ {

```
    access_by_lua_block {
        local opts = {
            redirect_uri_path = "/service_1/auth", -- we are send here after auth
            discovery = "https://<my-server>/keycloak/auth/realms/realm1/.well-known/openid-configuration",
            client_id = "openresty",
            client_secret = "<client1-secret>",
            session_contents = {id_token=true} -- this is essential for safari!
        }
        -- call introspect for OAuth 2.0 Bearer Access Token validation
        local res, err = require("resty.openidc").authenticate(opts)

        if err then
            ngx.status = 403
            ngx.say(err)
            ngx.exit(ngx.HTTP_FORBIDDEN)
        end
    }

    # I disabled caching so the browser won't cache the site.
    expires           0;
    add_header        Cache-Control private;

    proxy_pass http://<server-for-service1>:port1/foo/;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;

    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_buffering off;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";

}
```

..........................

```
location /service_2/ {

    access_by_lua_block {
        local opts = {
            redirect_uri_path = "/service_2/auth", -- we are send here after auth
            discovery = "https://<my-server>/keycloak/auth/realms/realm2/.well-known/openid-configuration",
            client_id = "openresty",
            client_secret = "client2-secret",
            session_contents = {id_token=true} -- this is essential for safari!
        }
        -- call introspect for OAuth 2.0 Bearer Access Token validation
        local res, err = require("resty.openidc").authenticate(opts)

        if err then
            ngx.status = 403
            ngx.say(err)
            ngx.exit(ngx.HTTP_FORBIDDEN)
        end
    }

    # I disabled caching so the browser won't cache the site.
    expires           0;
    add_header        Cache-Control private;

    proxy_pass http://<server-for-service2>:port2/bar/;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;

    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_buffering off;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";

}
```

[Edit-details 2]

I am using lua resty openidc version 1.7.2, but everything I write should stand for 1.7.4 based on the diff of the two version's code.

I can clearly see from the debug level logs that the session is created during the first access, and then reused on the second realm, which is wrong, as the second access still has a token for the first realm... Here is what the authorization for **realm2** looks like...:

```
2021/04/28 12:56:41 [debug] 2615#2615: *4617979 [lua] openidc.lua:1414: authenticate(): session.present=true, session.data.id_token=true, session.data.authenticated=true, opts.force_reauthorize=nil, opts.renew_access_token_on_expiry=nil, try_to_renew=true, token_expired=false
2021/04/28 12:56:41 [debug] 2615#2615: *4617979 [lua] openidc.lua:1470: authenticate(): id_token={"azp":"realm1","typ":"ID","iat":1619614598,"iss":"https:\/\/<myserver>\/keycloak\/auth\/realms\/realm1","aud":"realm1","nonce":"8c8ca2c4df2...b26"
,"jti":"1c028c65-...0994f","session_state":"0e1241e3-66fd-4ca1-a0dd-c0d1a6a5c708","email_verified":false,"sub":"25303e44-...e2c1757ae857","acr":"1","preferred_username":"logoutuser","auth_time":1619614598,"exp":1619614898,"at_hash":"5BNT...j414r72LU6g"}
```

Comment: "he is able to directly access the other service at realm2 as well." what you specifically mean by that?

Comment: added explanation, and my nginx.conf relevant details....

Comment: Are you using a user of the master realm for testing ?
if so this might happen.

Comment: No, both realms are not the master realm... Also, tried changing the client's names so that they are different in each realm... No luck....

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this took me some time. It may also be that most tutorials out there leave this **vulnerability (only in a setup where a single nginx is using multiple realms) of having authentication access one realm will allow authentication access to any other.**

a typical autentication call from tutorials out there is:

```
location /service1/ {

    access_by_lua_block {
        local opts = {
            redirect_uri_path = "/realm1/authenticated",
            discovery = "https://<myserver>/keycloak/auth/realms/realm1/.well-known/openid-configuration",
            client_id = "client1",
            client_secret = <........>,
            session_contents = {id_token=true} -- this is essential for safari!
        }
        -- call introspect for OAuth 2.0 Bearer Access Token validation
        local res, err = require("resty.openidc").authenticate(opts)

        if err then
            ngx.status = 403
            ngx.say(err)
            ngx.exit(ngx.HTTP_FORBIDDEN)
        end
    }

    # I disbled caching so the browser won't cache the site.
    expires           0;
    add_header        Cache-Control private;

    proxy_pass http://realm1-server:port/service1/;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;

    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_buffering off;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";

}
location /service2/ {
 <same for ream2> 
}
```

There seem actually to be two issues

1. We do not check for realm id (this is a vulnerability)
2. Sessions for the two realms are cached interchangeably (this would lead to a situation where if we fix (1), we would now be allowed to access only one realm and have to logout from realm1 to access realm2)

Solutions:
1)We need to explicitly check that the realm is correct
2)We should use one session table per realm (notice that although this would appear to solve (1) as well, it does not if an attacker mix and maches session ids with his "special" browser -- at least i think)

For no2 there was no documentation, I had to read the code of [openidc.lua](https://github.com/zmartzone/lua-resty-openidc/blob/master/lib/resty/openidc.lua) and from there the code for the library this library uses ([session.lua](https://github.com/bungle/lua-resty-session/blob/master/lib/resty/session.lua))

The changes are as follows:
location /service1/ {

```
    access_by_lua_block {
        local opts = {
            redirect_uri_path = "/realm1/authenticated",
            discovery = "https://<myserver>/keycloak/auth/realms/realm1/.well-known/openid-configuration",
            client_id = "client1",
            client_secret = <........>,
            session_contents = {id_token=true} -- this is essential for safari!
        }
        -- call introspect for OAuth 2.0 Bearer Access Token validation
        local res, err = require("resty.openidc").authenticate(opts,nil,nil,{name=opts.client_id})

        if (err or ( res.id_token.azp ~= opts.client_id ) ) then
            ngx.status = 403
            ngx.say(err)
            ngx.exit(ngx.HTTP_FORBIDDEN)
        end
    }
    <..................no changes here................>
}
location /service2/ {
 <same for ream2> 
}
```